# External static html view resolver + thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot project. There are some static HTML (without thymeleaf) and some with thymeleaf. Whenever I configure ResourceHandlers to serve static pages, it works fine to serve them. When I try to add ThymeleafViewResolver the static pages start to fail. Is there a way to create 2 view resolvers - one for thymeleaf othe rone for static htmls exclusive?

Static htmls are placed outside of jar, in an external folder. For thymeleaf it works just fine to put in a path "C:/Users/...", but for resourceHandlers it does not. Adding file:/// (for windows) does not work either.

Comment: It could be helpful https://o7planning.org/en/11257/using-multiple-viewresolvers-in-spring-boot

Comment: Did you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388230/configuring-multiple-view-resolvers-thymeleaf-and-json-spring